# Amazon SNS push notification special characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

I've been struggling with one particular thing in Amazon SNS push notifications which I can't find in any Amazon docs.

I'm trying to send a notification that contains `&` character and it happens that everything after `&` is stripped out.

`Try our new M&M's candy` becomes `Try our new M`. I haven't found any solution so far, so maybe someone here has faced the same issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you sending the message? If it is via code, please provide a sample of the code so that we can reproduce your situation. Have you tried sending such a message from the console, and did it work?

Comment: Either replace `&` by `%26` or `&amp;`. _(Not knowing Amazon SNS)_

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your message (i.e "***Try our new M&M's candy***") using the below payload and confirmed that special characters are working when included in the Push Notification payload:

**Payload :**

```
{
  "GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"text\": \"Try our new M&M's candy\" } }"
}
```

**Response :**

[image]

@Mikhail, can you kindly re-test and check if you are still experiencing this issue?